# Can't disable listeners when multiple conversations are clicked with Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, I have a chat client. The left div has a list of conversations, and the right div is labeled `#message-content`. When a user clicks on a conversation, it adds a listener, and generates the conversation in the message-content section. When they click on another conversation in the left div, the right div is wiped, and generates the new messages with a listener.

The problem is, it seems to hold onto the listeners, so if I view more than one conversation, and then receive a message, it generates n messages, where n is the amount of conversations I've clicked.

I assume I need to detach the listener from the PREVIOUS conversation, but I can't figure out how.

Here's the function that I call when a user clicks on an li element in the left hand side, it clears the `#message-content`, and runs:

```
var displayMessagesDetail = function (uid, chatID) {
    usersRef.child(`${uid}/chats/${chatID}/messages`).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

        let message = snapshot.val();
        let userClass = (message.user === auth.currentUser.uid ? 
            'message-bubble-self' : 
            'message-bubble-other'
        );

        $('#message-detail-content').append($('<p></p>').addClass(userClass).text(message.text));

    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you run `displayMessagesDetail`, the `.on()` method creates another listener. You should only run that function once when the chat is started.

Alternatively, you could deactivate the listener when you click another chat. You can  call `.off()` on `usersRef.child(${uid}/chats/${chatID}/messages)` where the and `chatID` and `uid` match the chat that you navigated away from. That would stop listening for any updates from that chat.

Comment: How would I accomplish this with just a single listener though? Is there a way to speak to that listener, and change the path? Because I guess I can have that one listener exist, and if a user clicks on another chat div, it will alter the listener path, and have it load the correct messages.

Comment: If you only want to have one active listener at a time, I'm pretty sure that you have to turn the old one off and create a new one each time you switch chats. I don't think you can modify active listeners. Try saving the active chat uid and chatID as variables, and every time you switch to a new chat, you could call `.off()` on the active chat. Then create a new listener and update your active chat variables

Comment: Ah great, thank you so much. Yeah I now shut off the listeners on a new message click, and all is working as it should. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help